# change data type of specific cell in a data table

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, cell

I have a data table with several columns. Is it possible to change the data type of one specific cell. Let's say column(2) is double. Can I put a string "Hello" into row(20), Column(2)?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: You could make the column type Object and put anything you want in it but I wouldn't recommend it. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Hi Marry, because I need put the datatable to a report. My report has several columns, MODEL #, DESCRIPTION, UNIT PRICE, DISCOUNT, QTY, EXTENDED PRICE. I manually add a subtotal row and a blank row between different models. I want put a string "Subtotal" in UNIT PRICE column to make the report look better. If I put it in DESCRIPTION column, it is too far from the Subtotal Price.

Comment: The entire column has to be the same type.  So to have multiple types in a column you need to use object like Mary said.  I have used object in column of table myself when needed.  So make sure you have a valid reason.

Comment: Hi Mary, the error is System.ArgumentException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <Subtotal> in Unit Price Column.  Expected type is Double.'